# How to access different variables with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I am trying to get a user to be prompted with the option to enter a value between 1 and 5, and get access a different array index based on the number they entered.

```
<h1>JavaScript Arrays</h1>

<p>JavaScript array elements are accessed using numeric indexes (starting from 1).</p>

<h2 id="whichbar"></h2>

<script>
    var chocbars = ["Mars Bar","Chokito","Boost","Crunchie","Picnic"];

    var userchoice = prompt ('Please enter a value between 1 and 5');

    document.getElementById("whichbar").innerHTML = chocbars[4];

</script>
```

I expect that the user is prompted for a value between 1 and 5, this value then determines which chocolate bar is returned to the screen.

Comment: use `chocbars[userchoice - 1]` ? Also, array elements are accessed starting from 0, hence the `- 1`

Comment: You have to add a `+` before the prompt or else the resultant would be a string type.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt you won't have to since - 1 will convert it to a number for you

Comment: @Kobe Yeah, with -1, the conversion is taken care

Comment: Thank you all very much, this was helpful. Much appreciated.I apologise for the unnecessary lines at the beginning of my explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the index of the array by getting a zero based value, hence indices start with zero.

```
document.getElementById("whichbar").innerHTML = chocbars[userchoice - 1];
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is helpful, also i apologise for the unnecessary line at the beginning.